# Не выводить Div если в url содежится определенное значение

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть код

```
<div class="category_description">
<?php echo $this->category->category_description; ?>
</div>
```

Как сделать так чтобы div не выводился если в каком-то url присутствует значение start ?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, как-нибудь так:

```
<?php
    if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'start')===false) {
?>
        <div class="category_description">
        <?php echo $this->category->category_description; ?>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но код именно показывает div если есть start. Подскажите, как не показывать div если есть start ?

Comment: заменил !==false на ==false и заработало как надо. Это корректно ? Спасибо!

Comment: Тогда, чтобы отрабатывалось верно, три равно должны быть === , не два... если поставить два равно == , то в случае, когда некий start будет встречен в самом начале (на нулевом символе), то вернется значение 0 (т.е. false) и код будет показан.